# Proving the injectivity of this function

Tags: functions, exponential-function

> Let   *exp*$:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^+} ; 
> exp(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac{x^k}{k!})$ for $\forall
> \  x\in\mathbb{Q}$

I am trying to prove that this fuction is injective. Usually, I just use differentiation to check if a given function is monotonic and thus injective, but I don't think this  will work given the domain.

Comment: You don't know that all those terms are positive.  $1>-2$ but $1^2<(-2)^2$

Comment: Hint:  Note that $y>0\implies \exp(y)>1$ (why?).  And that the binomial theorem tells us that $\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\times \exp(y)$.

Comment: @lulu Yes, you are right. I somehow forgot that the domain included negative numbers too.

Comment: Can you use the fact that $\exp$ maps sums into products?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Is it trivial to prove that this definition is consistent with e^x?

Comment: No. But it's not hard either.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Proving injectivity using the properties of exponents is easy, but I would have to prove them too. Is there any nice way to determine injectivity without them?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: @lulu Could you elaborate on how the binomial theorem implies that $exp(x+y)=exp(x)\cdot exp(y)$

Comment: This is just the binomial theorem.   Well, you have to prove that absolutely convergent power series multiply the way they ought to, which does require some work.  Rudin's standard text works along these lines (that is, they use no other definition for $e^x$ than the power series, and deduce all the usual properties from that).

Comment: If you ignore the power series issues, then the argument is just :  $\exp(x)\times \exp(y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {x^n}{n!}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac {y^m}{m!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac 1{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac {x^ky^{n-k}}{k!(n-k)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac 1{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkx^ky^{n-k}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {(x+y)^n}{n!}=\exp(x+y)$

Comment: You are aware of the fact that $\exp$ does *not* map $\Bbb Q$ into itself, right?!